# call method in activity from service

Tags: android

I have a service that show me a list of information using toast.
some of my used function should be in activity (function to get list of call history ....). that activity are used only for my function it had no graphic .the functions can not be static it show me error , i essay to use interface but always error 
please help me to use those function from my activity. 
NB:- i read all anser about problem like this but it is the same thing nothing change
- the service had no relation with the activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you are not following a standard design pattern for interacting an activity with the service.
Please re-think the case of activity service interaction.
If you want to reuse the method for getting the call records, put this method in an utils class and pass a context to get the call logs-

```
private static String getCallDetails(Context context) {
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
        null, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
int number = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
int type = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
int duration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);       
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String phNumber = cursor.getString(number);
    String callType = cursor.getString(type);
    String callDate = cursor.getString(date);
    Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
    String callDuration = cursor.getString(duration);
    String dir = null;
    int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
    switch (dircode) {
    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
        dir = "OUTGOING";
        break;
    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
        dir = "INCOMING";
        break;

    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
        dir = "MISSED";
        break;
    }
    stringBuffer.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber + " \nCall Type:--- "
            + dir + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime
            + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration);
    stringBuffer.append("\n----------------------------------");
}
cursor.close();
return stringBuffer.toString();
```

}

You can get context in the service by using the method calls-

```
          getBaseContext();
          getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: thanx  a lot this solve my problem at first i used managetQuery for this it dosn"t work but now it works like a charm